# Excel Chart colorize 3D bars

Tags: c#, excel, charts, interop

Colorzing a 3D-Bar chart with Excel and interop does not work:

Creation of chart:

```
chartRange = xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlsSheet.Cells[array.GetLength(0), array.GetLength(1)]];
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumn;
chartPage.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet, oOpt);
```

Changing color:

```
Excel.Series series = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(1);
Excel.Point pt = series.Points(2);
pt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbPink;
```

Problem: Nothing will change inside the chart, but there is also no error. Just showing this random colors on the bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the order of the statements is important:

```
chartRange = xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlsSheet.Cells[array.GetLength(0), array.GetLength(1)]];
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows);

Excel.Series series = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(1);
Excel.Point pt = series.Points(2);
pt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbPink;

chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumn;
chartPage.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet, oOpt);
```

worked for me